# Arduino - cannot get buzzer to buzz

Tags: arduino

I've hooked up a buzzer to pin 13 & ground on my Arduino.

The "Blink" example works fine and the buzzer sounds every second off and on as expected.

However, when I try to do the same buzz with my code, I can't get it to buzz upon a specific event. This is a homegrown security system - when the door is opened, I want the Arduino to check a PHP page which returns "armed" if the system has been armed.

Everything else seems to work except the buzzer part.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0xD3, 0x6C };
char serverName[] = "mysite.com";
String currentLine = "";
String armed = "No";

int nFrontWindow = 0;
int sFrontWindow = 1;
int kitchenWindow = 2;
int bedroomWindow = 3;
int frontDoor = 4;

int val0 = 0;
int val1 = 0;
int val2 = 0;
int val3 = 0;
int val4 = 0;

int threshold0 = 20;
int threshold1 = 20;
int threshold2 = 20;
int threshold3 = 20;
int threshold4 = 20;

int breach0 = 0;
int breach1 = 0;
int breach2 = 0;
int breach3 = 0;
int breach4 = 0;

int alarm0 = 0;
int alarm1 = 0;
int alarm2 = 0;
int alarm3 = 0;
int alarm4 = 0;

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if(Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) { // start ethernet using mac & IP address
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");  
    while(true)   // no point in carrying on, so stay in endless loop:
      ;
  }
  delay(1000); // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize
}

void loop() {           

  // read the analog in values:
  val0 = analogRead(nFrontWindow); 
  val1 = analogRead(sFrontWindow);
  val2 = analogRead(kitchenWindow);
  val3 = analogRead(bedroomWindow);
  val4 = analogRead(frontDoor);

  // print the analog in values:                     

  if (val0 > threshold0)
  {
    Serial.print("nFrontWindow: ");
    Serial.print(val0); 
    Serial.print("\n");
    if (alarm0)
    {
      if (breach0 < 10)
        breach0++;
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach0 > 9)
      {
        alarm0 = 1;
        send_alert(0);
      }
      else
        breach0++;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    if (alarm0)
    {
      if (breach0 > 0)
        breach0--;
      else
      {
        alarm0 = 0;
        send_alert(10);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach0 > 0)
        breach0--;
    }
  }

  if (val1 > threshold1)
  {
    Serial.print("sFrontWindow: ");
    Serial.print(val1); 
    Serial.print("\n");
    if (alarm1)
    {
      if (breach1 < 10)
        breach1++;
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach1 > 9)
      {
        alarm1 = 1;
        send_alert(1);
      }
      else
        breach1++;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    if (alarm1)
    {
      if (breach1 > 0)
        breach1--;
      else
      {
        alarm1 = 0;
        send_alert(11);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach1 > 0)
        breach1--;
    }
  }

  if (val2 > threshold2)
  {
    Serial.print("kitchenWindow: ");
    Serial.print(val2); 
    Serial.print("\n");
    if (alarm2)
    {
      if (breach2 < 10)
        breach2++;
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach2 > 9)
      {
        alarm2 = 1;
        send_alert(2);
      }
      else
        breach2++;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    if (alarm2)
    {
      if (breach2 > 0)
        breach2--;
      else
      {
        alarm2 = 0;
        send_alert(12);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach2 > 0)
        breach2--;
    }
  }

  if (val3 > threshold3)
  {
    Serial.print("bedroomWindow: ");
    Serial.print(val3); 
    Serial.print("\n");
    if (alarm3)
    {
      if (breach3 < 10)
        breach3++;
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach3 > 9)
      {
        alarm3 = 1;
        send_alert(3);
      }
      else
        breach3++;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    if (alarm3)
    {
      if (breach3 > 0)
        breach3--;
      else
      {
        alarm3 = 0;
        send_alert(13);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach3 > 0)
        breach3--;
    }
  }

  if (val4 > threshold4)
  {
    Serial.print("frontDoor: ");
    Serial.print(val4);
    Serial.print("\n");

    if (alarm4)
    {
      if (breach4 < 10)
        breach4++;
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach4 > 9)
      {
        alarm4 = 1;
        send_alert(4);
      }
      else
        breach4++;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    if (alarm4)
    {
      if (breach4 > 0)
        breach4--;
      else
      {
        alarm4 = 0;
        send_alert(14);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (breach4 > 0)
        breach4--;
    }
  }

  delay(100);                     
}

void send_alert(int pin)
{
  if (client.connect(serverName, 80)>0) {
    client.flush();
    Serial.print("\nconnected... ");

    String link = "GET [PHP FILE GOES HERE]";
    link += pin;
    link += " HTTP/1.1";

    Serial.print("Sending alert code: ");
    Serial.print(pin);
    Serial.print("\n\n");


    client.println(link);
    client.println("Host: mysite.com");
    client.println("User-Agent: arduino-ethernet");
    client.println("Connection: close");  
    client.println();
    delay(3000);

  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    //handle this
  }
    Serial.print("Server response:\n");
    Serial.print("----------------\n");
    while(client.available()){
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.print(c);
      currentLine += c;
      if (c == '\n') {
        currentLine = "";
      }

      if (currentLine.endsWith("armed"))
      {
        if (pin == 4 || pin == 3 || pin == 2 || pin == 1 || pin == 0)
        {
          Serial.print("\nBZZZZZZZZZZ\n");
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
          delay(1000);              // wait for a second
          digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
          delay(1000);              // wait for a second
        }
      }
    }
    Serial.print("\n----------------\n");

    //else
     //  Serial.println("result not found");
    client.stop();
    client.flush();
}
```

Comment: Please simplify your code, what 's wrong ? Do you get the expected output on Serial ? Think about factorize duplicated code.

Comment: Yes, I need to simplify the code a bit, there's a lot of duplication. But yes, I do get the expected output on Serial - I see the phrase "BZZZZZZZZZZ" printed, but the buzzer does not sound.

Comment: Does the [Blink example](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink) still work?

Comment: Yes, the Blink example works fine if I load that - and it's the exact same code put towards the bottom of the snippet above. I'm stumped at this point because the "BZZZZZZZZZZ" part is printed on the Serial console, but the buzzer doesn't sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that pin 13 is used by the Ethernet Shield. So are pin 10, 11, and 12. So use a pin other then them.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is that you aren't generating a square wave to make sound the buzzer.
Since you are using Arduino you can just use tone() and noTone() functions, well explained in [Arduino site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone).